# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload with Codeigniter 2.1

Tags: jquery, file, codeigniter, upload, blueimp

Im tryign to install the [jQuery File Upload 6.5 with CodeIgniter 2.1](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-6.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1) into my Codeigniter script and Im facing some problems.

At first Im using 2.1.3 CI version with "Modular Extensions - HMVC(version 5.4)" as third_party into my application folder.

I want to create a module "upload" by using the blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. I have followed the instruductions as described there but nothing works.

The problem is that I'm getting in developer console the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null      main.js:31
POST url/upload/upload_img 500 (Internal Server Error)     jquery.js:8416
```

*The 500 error showed when Im starting the upload. The truth is that upload_img url has never opened.*

Here is my code:

**application/config/constants.php**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

define('FOPEN_READ',                            'rb');
define('FOPEN_READ_WRITE',                      'r+b');
define('FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE_DESTRUCTIVE',        'wb'); // truncates existing file data, use with care
define('FOPEN_READ_WRITE_CREATE_DESTRUCTIVE',   'w+b'); // truncates existing file data, use with care
define('FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE',                    'ab');
define('FOPEN_READ_WRITE_CREATE',               'a+b');
define('FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE_STRICT',             'xb');
define('FOPEN_READ_WRITE_CREATE_STRICT',        'x+b');

// Define Ajax Request
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

**application/config/routes**

```
$route['upload'] = 'upload/upload';
$route['upload/upload_img'] = 'upload/upload/upload_img';
$route['upload/deleteImage'] = 'upload/upload/deleteImage';
$route['upload/get_files'] = 'upload/upload/get_files';
```

**application/modules/uplaod/controllers/upload**

Exactly the same as [this controller](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-6.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1).
The only changes is in construct:

```
 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        //Set relative Path with CI Constant
        $this->setPath_img_upload_folder("uploads/dress/img/");
        $this->setPath_img_thumb_upload_folder("uploads/dress/img/thumbnails/");
        //Delete img url
        $this->setDelete_img_url(base_url() . '/upload/deleteImage/');
        //Set url img with Base_url()
        $this->setPath_url_img_upload_folder(base_url() . "uploads/dress/img/");
        $this->setPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder(base_url() . "uploads/dress/img/thumbnails/");

  }
  public function index() {
  $this->load->view('upload_form');
  }
```

**js/main.js**

exactly the same as described in original post.

**application/modules/upload/view/upload_form**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin Demo 6.11
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Demo</title>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bar and preview images for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads. Works with any server-side platform (Google App Engine, PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS Toolkit styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/blueimp/css/style.css">
<!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
<!-- Bootstrap Image Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/blueimp/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/blueimp/css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
<!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="upload/upload_img" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>

        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>

            <!-- The global progress information -->
            <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
    </form>


</div>
<!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
<div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade" data-filter=":odd" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-image"></div></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon-download"></i>
            <span>Download</span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
            <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
            <span>Slideshow</span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
            <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
            <span>Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
            <span>Next</span>
            <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="/blueimp/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="/blueimp/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload file processing plugin -->
<script src="/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="/blueimp/js/main.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE8+ -->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->
</body> 
</html>
```

all links (js and css) are working, I have checked twice.

**.htaccess**

maybe the problem is here, cause using the "jquery-file-upload.appspot.com" into form's action, the script working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    # NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
    #AllowOverride All
    #RewriteBase /

    # Restrict your site to only one domain
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

#prevent access to htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all

</Files>

#disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: Im getting in console log this error:

POST http://url/upload/upload_img 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: maybe CI .htaccess is the problem..